# How to get single row using Group By and Having on column containing varchar value

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have a table containing N columns, taking for sample like

```
Dept_ID User_ID Data
--------------------
1       A       J
1       S       J
1       J       J
2       J       J
2       K       J
2       K       L
3       j       L
3       J       L
```

Now, In case there is more than one data set for a Dept_ID which contain differently set flags for User_ID, only the data set with User_ID = ‘J’ is to be selected.

I have tried using

```
SELECT dept_id, USER_ID 
FROM DELETEME 
GROUP BY dept_id, USER_ID
HAVING USER_ID = 'J' 
ORDER BY DEPT_ID
```

However this is giving me results .

```
Dept_ID User_ID
---------------
1       J
2       J
3       J
```

But my requirement is,

```
Dept_ID User_ID Data
--------------------
1       J       J
2       J       J
3       J       L
```

Please suggest.

Comment: What are you planning on doing with this information?  If you really have duplicated data in your table, the best thing to do is remove it (in which case this is a duplicate question).   If your data isn't really duplicated, do you have a specific criteria for choosing one row over the other?  Or does another column make the row unique, but you only want unique rows for this subset of data?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Distinct Dept_ID,USER_ID, Data 
 FROM @DELETEME
 WHERE USER_ID='J'
 Order by Dept_ID



Dept_ID User_ID Data
--------------------
1       J       J
2       J       J
3       J       L
```

Comment: What?  No.  I'm not sure how you think this is related.  This is a somewhat unusual (and likely poorly performing) way to find duplicate `lastName` values.